# combine two methods returning two different values

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ado.net

Hi I have got  two methods are returning two different return type of  values like int and string and I am executing query inside the method with passing different variables like the below

**METHOD 1**

```
private string SelectTransactionHistory(int transactionId, ContextObject contextObject)
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    con = new SqlConnection(contextObject.ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    string returnvalue = string.Empty;            
    string selecteQuery = "SELECT Comments 
                           From dbo.TransactionHistory 
                           WHERE TransactionID = '" + transactionId + "'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(selecteQuery, con);
    returnvalue = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();            
    return returnvalue;        
 }
```

**METHOD 2**

```
private int SelectTransactionHistoryID(string comment, ContextObject contextObject)
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    con = new SqlConnection(contextObject.ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    string query = "SELECT TransactionID  
                    From dbo.TransactionHistory 
                    WHERE Comments = '" + comment + "'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    int returnvalue = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    return returnvalue;
}
```

I am calling these methods in another method like this

```
int transactionId = SelectTransactionHistoryID(comment, GetContext()); 
string commentsreturnValue = SelectTransactionHistory(transactionId, GetContext());
```

how can i combine these two methods to make  more generic type..
Would any one have any suggestions on how to do this..
Many Thanks.....

Comment: How about `out` parameters?

Comment: What do you mean with "combine"? Is there any sense in sequential call of these methods? Also, please, use parameters in queries to prevent SQL injection, and `using`s to release resources.

Comment: Will you only ever have two or could you add more in future?

Comment: hmm is it possible to make single method and passing variables to that method thanks for your suggestion ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a method to execute any query using ado.net, for sample:

```
private static T ExecuteQuery<T>(ContextObject contextObject, string query)
{
    T result;
    using (SqlConnection con = con = new SqlConnection(contextObject.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                result = (T)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            result = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }   
    returnr result;  
}
```

And pass a query that return a single value (in sql we use `TOP 1`), something like this:

```
var resultComment = ExecuteQuery<string>("SELECT TOP 1 Comments From dbo.TransactionHistory WHERE TransactionID = '" + transactionId + "'");
var resultTransactionId = ExecuteQuery<int>("SELECT TOP 1 TransactionID  From dbo.TransactionHistory WHERE Comments = '" + comment + "'")
```

Comment: many thanks for this solution and I am looking for this one ... i am calling those methods inside test method ...so is it possible to write select command inside Execute query ...

Comment: You can pass any query to this method and it will execute for you and give a `T` value result. Remember to check it as an awnser if it help you to find the final solution :)

Comment: Oh the error handling here is making me cry. Just let the error bubble up.

Answer (score 1):

I have all of my infrastructure classes setup to utilize [`Dapper`](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). However you can replace the dapper extension method with a regular method.

Base Service:

```
public interface IService
{
     T Execute<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> query);
     void Execute(Action<IDbConnection> query);
}

public sealed class Service : IService
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public Service(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    private IDbConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.Open();

        return connection;
    }

    public T Execute<T>(Func<IDbConnection, T> query)
    {
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            return query(connection);
        }
    }

    public void Execute(Action<IDbConnection> query)
    {
        using (var connection = CreateConnection())
        {
            query(connection);
        }
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class TransactionHistory
{
    public int TransactionID { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface ITransactionHistoryService
{
    IEnumerable<TransactionHistory> GetByTransactionId(int transactionId);
    IEnumerable<TransactionHistory> GetByComment(string comment);
}

public sealed class TransactionHistoryService : ITransactionHistoryService
{
    // Note SELECT * is frowned upon. Replace with actual column names.
    private const string GetByTransactionIdQuery =
        "SELECT * FROM dbo.TransactionHistory WHERE TransactionID = @TransactionId";
    private const string GetByCommentQuery =
        "SELECT * FROM dbo.TransactionHistory WHERE Comments = @Comment";
    private readonly IService _service;

    public TransactionHistoryService(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TransactionHistory> GetByTransactionId(int transactionId)
    {
        var result = _service.Execute(c =>
                                        c.Query<TransactionHistory>(GetByTransactionIdQuery,
                                                                    new { TransactionId = transactionId }));

        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TransactionHistory> GetByComment(string comment)
    {
        var result = _service.Execute(c =>
                                        c.Query<TransactionHistory>(GetByCommentQuery,
                                                                    new { Comment = comment }));

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single function as follows- (Not tested)

```
private string[] SelectTransactionHistory(int transactionId, ContextObject contextObject)
{
        string[] returnValues;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        con = new SqlConnection(contextObject.ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        string returnvalue = string.Empty;
        string selecteQuery = "SELECT TransactionID, Comments From dbo.TransactionHistory WHERE TransactionID = '" + transactionId + "'";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(selecteQuery, con);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            returnValues[0] = reader["TransactionID"].ToString();
            returnValues[1] = reader["Comments"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
        return returnValues; 
}
```

And then call it as follows-

```
string[] TransactionHistory = SelectTransactionHistory(transactionId, GetContext());
int transactionId = Convert.ToInt32(TransactionHistory[0]);
string commentsreturnValue = TransactionHistory[1];
```

**The above code is not tested. But you can get an idea.**